# FourSquare Brand Use Clarifications

Tags: foursquare, branding

An account manager that I work with has come up to me and insists that the Foursquare API can be used to "checkin" *to* a website, so basically saying one could checkin to www.somewebsite.com (this differs from checking into a venue via a website). Admittedly the language on the brand page [creative use FAQ](https://foursquare.com/business/brands/usecases/consumerpackagedgoods) on foursquare.com reads a little odd:

- Building “check-ins” into your own application or website

Has the FS API been used to do such a thing? I couldn't see how, or why FourSquare would allow this capability. I do see they have Brand pages which looks nothing more that what Twitter might accomplish.

On another note, where does someone contact FS regarding a branded promotion like the one they have done for SuperBowl Sunday? There is nothing on the site to let someone know where to contact them.

Answer (score 2):

Foursquare check-ins are to venues, and venues always have a physical location associated with them. So no, you can't check in to www.somewebsite.com. What you *can* do is use the API to check in *from* www.somewebsite.com.

To contact foursquare about partnership opportunities, e-mail partners@foursquare.com

Answer (score 0):

The foursquare API is for checking into locations. What the FAQ is telling you is that you can make an application that allows people to check in to a location from that application.

Let me give you a potential example.

A restaurant has a loyalty club where you register online and can check into the restaurant when you arrive, for coupons. But the restaurant also allows you to link your restaurant account with your foursquare account.  So the next time you show up at the restaurant, you enter your phone number and presto, you're also checked into foursquare.

It might not be a great application, but it's an example of something that could be done and the type of application to which the FAQ was referring, not checking into a website itself.

as for the branding question, check out their [Merchant Platform](https://foursquare.com/business/merchants) page.